# Pass login messages to tmux

Tags: shell, login, pam

When I login, I connect to a tmux session (either by exec'ing tmux if there is no current session, or exec'ing tmux attach if there is).
However this means I don't see the login messages (/etc/issue, /etc/motd, amount of mail etc., the stuff that pam provides). Is there a way to get the messages printed inside the tmux session? (The solution should only rely on POSIX shell syntax i.e. not be bash/zsh/other shell specific)

Comment: Does starting a shell as a login shell (`bash -l`, `ksh -l` etc.) show all this information?

Comment: I guess so, but it also doesn't include ssh login details (afaik), when I have time I might test this (and answer with my current workaround).

Answer (score 2):

For your `~/.bashrc` and/or `~/.zshrc`:

```
if [ -n "$TMUX" ]; then

  # render /etc/issue or else fall back to kernel/system info
  agetty --show-issue 2>/dev/null || uname -a

  # message of the day
  for motd in /run/motd.dynamic /etc/motd; do
    if [ -s "$motd" ]; then cat "$motd"; break; fi
  done

  # last login
  last $USER |awk 'NR==2 {
    if (NF==10) { i=1; if ($3!~/^:/) from = " from " $3 }
    printf("Last login: %s %s %s %s%s on %s\n",
      $(3+i), $(4+i), $(5+i), $(6+i), from, $2);
    exit
  }'

  # mail check
  if [ -s "/var/mail/$USER" ] # may need to change to /var/spool/mail/$USER
    then echo "You have $(grep -c '^From ' "/var/mail/$USER") mails."
    else echo "You have no mail."
  fi
fi
```

`agetty --show-issue` requires util-linux 2.35+. I put a workaround for older versions in [see /etc/issue as parsed by agetty](https://serverfault.com/a/1106799/209449).

I couldn't figure out how to replicate the login system's view of last login, so I reconstructed it with `last` and `awk`. Your current login should be `NR==1` (the first numeric record), so your last login should be `NR==2`. Ten fields means there was a remote login and therefore the host field is not empty: note `i=1` and populate a `from` variable to note it. Then print the timestamp, which either starts with the third field (`$(3+i)` when `i` is uninitialized and defaults to `0`) or the fourth.

Most systems just say "you have mail" or "you have no mail", but I seem to recall seeing some system quantifying it and that was easy enough to replicate, so this mail check actually counts your messages with grep. This shouldn't cost you any more than a half second unless your mailbox is enormous, in which case you should really fix that. Note that there are two locations you need to change if your mail spool is located elsewhere (I didn't want to set any variables because they'd persist into the shell session, though you could always define and then `unset` them).

Answer (score 0):

Add these lines to your `.bashrc`:

```
declare TMUX
MOTD="/etc/motd"
ISSUE="/etc/issue"

if [ ! -z "$TMUX" ]; then
  if [ -f "$MOTD" ]; then
    cat "$MOTD"
    exit
  elif [ -f "$ISSUE" ]; then
    cat "$ISSUE"
    exit
  else
    :
  fi
fi
```

These will check if you are inside or outside a tmux session. If inside, then check if `/etc/motd` or `/etc/issue` is existed. If any existed, print its contents.

Comment: I had this but isn't a real solution as 1. issue has flags which must be interpreted (so cat'ing it doesn't work) and 2. This doesn't get all of the output from login such as mail, last login etc.

Comment: @JamesTocknell /etc/issue is displayed BEFORE you login. So you have already seen it when you've started your tmux session.