# Keep Last Login Message on Tmux

Tags: terminal, tmux, alacritty

all I am new to use Tmux and Alacritty as my main terminal emulator in my MacBook. In my `Alacritty.config` file, I set shell to be

```
shell: 
program: /opt/homebrew/bin/tmux
  args:
    - new-session
    - -A
    - -D
    - -s
    - main
```

Therefore, when I open Alacritty, Tmux will run a the same time. However, if I do it in this way, I will lose the Last login message in like attached picture.
[image]

Though I know that this message is not that important, I really want to add back this Last Login message back in Alacrittty& Tmux.

Answer (score 0):

I solved my problem by adding a config file in home directory `~/`. First I create a file `.tmux_last_login` in home directory.

```
# This file should be place in ~/ directory
if [ -n "$TMUX" ]; then
  # Display last login info when starting a new shell in tmux
  last $USER | awk 'NR==2 {
    if (NF==10) { i=1; if ($3 !~ /^:/) from = " from " $3 }
    printf("Last login: %s %s %s %s%s on %s\n", $(3+i), $(4+i), $(5+i), $(6+i), from, $2);
    exit
  }'
fi
```

This method is copied from [this post](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/119085/pass-login-messages-to-tmux). Next, I include `source ~/.tmux_last_login` in my `~/.zshrc` file. If you have `Powerlevel10K` config in `.zshrc`, you may need to put `source ~/.tmux_last_login` before the configuration of `Powerlevel10k`.